# Yii2 Gridview Fields Showing as "(not set)" if they appear more than once in the database

Tags: yii2

[What gridview is displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtqQ0.png)

[Applicant Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAwQ6.png)

[Department Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXRAj.png)

[Application Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEkeA.png)

[Before Searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbAzy.png)

[After Searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMlB6.png)

I'm having issues with values showing up as "(not set)" if they appear more than once in the database, and Im not sure why. Is there something I'm missing?

My model:

```
    public function getApplication()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Application::className(), ['id' => 'application_id']);
    }
    public function getApplicant()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Applicant::className(), ['id' => 'applicant_id'])
        ->via('application');
    }

    public function getDepartment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Department::className(), ['id' => 'department_id'])
        ->via('applicant');
    }
```

My Controller:

```
        $searchModel = new ApplicationShiftSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);

    }
```

Search function:

```
    public function search($params)
    {
    $role_id = User::getRole();

    //If can see admin or VP
    if ($role_id == '4' || $role_id == 3){
             $query = ApplicationShift::find()->joinWith(['application','applicant','faculty','department','floor','building','shift']);
    }
    //If can see at a faculty level
    elseif ($role_id == '2'){
        $faculty = User::getFacultyArray();
        $query = ApplicationShift::find()->joinWith(['application','applicant','faculty','department','floor','building','shift'])->where(['faculty.id' => $faculty]);
    }

    //If can see at department level
    elseif ($role_id == '1') {
        $departments = User::getDepartmentArray();
        $query = ApplicationShift::find()->joinWith(['application','applicant','faculty','department','floor','building','shift'])->where(['department.id' => $departments]);

    }


        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['applicant'] = [

        'asc' => ['applicant.name' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['applicant.name' => SORT_DESC],
    ];

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['building'] = [

                'asc' => ['building.name' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['building.name' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['floor'] = [

                'asc' => ['floor.floor' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['floor.floor' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['shift'] = [

                'asc' => ['shift.name' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['shift.name' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['application'] = [

                'asc' => ['application.status' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['application.status' => SORT_DESC],
        ];


    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['faculty'] = [

        'asc' => ['faculty.name' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['faculty.name' => SORT_DESC],
    ];

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['department'] = [

        'asc' => ['department.name' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['department.name' => SORT_DESC],
    ];

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }
        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'shift_id' => $this->shift_id,
            'application_id' => $this->application_id,
            'application_shift.number' => $this->number,
        'building.name' => $this->building,
        'department.name' => $this->department,
            'shift.name' => $this->shift,
        'faculty.name' => $this->faculty,
        'application.status' => $this->application,
        'shift.name' => $this->shift,

        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'applicant.name', $this->applicant])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'floor.floor', $this->floor]);

    return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

It seems that the data is fetching 5 rows, but it's only showing the data the first time it shows up. Does anyone know why? I feel like Im missing something really obvious...

Comment: You should add the code of `search()` method of your `ApplicationShiftSearch` class so we can see how the query looks like. Also it might be good idea to include the structure of all involved tables not just one.

Comment: I've updated it with the search code, the structures are pretty basic but I have to grab from a bunch of different db's so it would be posting a lot, theyre pretty general